# How to get business hours details programmatically in Dynamics 365

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I have several SLAs in my Dynamics 365 ORG. Every SLA have different business hours attach to it.

I have a requirement that needs to fetch the details of the business hours in the SLA programmatically (call within plugin/custom workflow).

The details that I need will be:

- The working hours each day (e.g Monday 8 - 5, Tuesday 8.30 - 5.30, etc)
- The list of break time
- The List of holidays attached

Have tried using retrievemultiple and CRM Message like QueryScheduleRequest and ExpandCalendarRequest but so far haven't manage to get all the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get business hours (calendar) details manually but there are quite a few steps. I've outlined them below roughly, but I'd recommend you create a quick console application to debug and step through the attributes available to you in real time.

First query for the SLA you want. If you have the ID then use:

```
var sla = service.Retrieve("sla", ID, new ColumnSet(new string[] { "businesshoursid" });
```

Then get the ID of the business hours associated with the SLA:

```
var businessHoursId = sla.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("businesshoursid").Id;
```

Then retrieve the business hours (calendar) itself:

```
var calendar = service.Retrieve("calendar", businessHoursId, new ColumnSet(true));
```

A calendar can have multiple rules. Retrieve them using:

```
var calendarRules = calendar.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("calendarrules");
```

These outer calendar rules will have a pattern which you can see using

```
var firstRulePattern = calendarRules[0].GetAttributeValue<string>("pattern");
// FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
```

But to get the working hours each day, you'll need the inner calendars. Using the first rule as an example:

```
var innerCalendarId = calendarRules[0].GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("innercalendarid").Id;
var innerCalendar = service.Retrieve("calendar", innerCalendarId, new ColumnSet(true);
var innnerCalendarRule = innerCalendar.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("calendarrules").Entities.FirstOrDefault();
```

From your inner rule, note the attributes `duration` and `offset`. These values are in minutes and will give you the working hours each day.

Comment: Thanks Dave! Just to add more, found out that the calendar rule inside inner calendar have attributes called "subcode" from that we can determine whether it's working hour or break time.

Answer (score 0):

**QuerySchedulerRequest** returns the working hours for any resource(user, equipment....etc) considering the business closures

```
    // Retrieve the working hours of the current user.                                              
                QueryScheduleRequest scheduleRequest = new QueryScheduleRequest
                {
                    ResourceId = userResponse.UserId,
                    Start = DateTime.Now,
                    End = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7),
                    TimeCodes = new TimeCode[] { TimeCode.Available }
                };
                QueryScheduleResponse scheduleResponse = (QueryScheduleResponse)service.Execute(scheduleRequest);

                // Verify if some data is returned for the availability of the current user
                if (scheduleResponse.TimeInfos.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully queried the working hours of the current user.");
                }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/org-service/samples/query-working-hours-user

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.queryschedulerequest?view=dataverse-sdk-latest

Comment: Rather than posting the same answer on multiple questions, please flag one of them as a duplicate.